"Sandbox: rsync.samba(1384) deny(1) file-write-create" even if User Script Sandboxing is already no
my project with Google Mobile Ad SDK pod is facing a lot of issues. It's now the one in the title.
Literally every post I found is about setting the User Script Sandboxing in the build option to no. But mine is already no. Any advice?
A little more info, at first it was "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code". I cleaned the build folder and rebuild. It changed to "Sandbox: rsync.samba([some other number]) deny(1) file-read-data". Cleaned and rebuild again. Then this time it changed to the title one. Not sure if this is relevant.
Many many thanks!

Did you make sure to update the setting for the target as well as the main project?

Sorry for coming back this late.  I actually rebuilt my whole project and now face another issue.  Also, I know nothing about target.  Will google it. Thanks!

I had the same issue and the User Script Sandboxing is already set to No. So what I figured out is that this issue was related to access permissions on disk to Derived Data, see this answer
